# os.walk works in the editor but not on the python window (On Windows)

Tags: python, file

I'm working on a project to create a python script that will find a specific word in a .txt document.
Here's my code:

```
import os
import time
import string
 
 
while True:
    file_name = input("Quel est le nom du fichier que vous souhaitez parcourir ? ")
    time.sleep(2)

    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        if file_name in files:
            fichier = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            print("Fichier trouvé :", fichier)
            time.sleep(2)
            mot_choisi = input("Quel mot cherchez-vous ? ").lower()

            with open(fichier, 'r') as file:
                for i, ligne in enumerate(file):
                    mots = ligne.lower().split()
                    for index, mot in enumerate(mots):
                        mot = mot.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
                        if mot == mot_choisi:
                            print(f'Le mot est en position {index} dans la ligne numéro {i}:\n{ligne}')
            break
    else:
        print("Le fichier n'a pas été trouvé")
```

My problem is that when I use it in my editor (Visual Studio Code), It works perfectly.
But if I try to use it by opening the file with python itself It says that the file can't be found (I am absolutely sure I put the right name)

The goal is for it to work with only the name of the file instead of the whole path.
Which works on the editor but not on the python window

Comment: Does the path `.` mean the same thing in both circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same Python installation in both places. Do a `print(sys.path)` to confirm.

Then make sure that the filename contains only ASCII letters (e.g. no accents) and no spaces. For testing purposes, just name it `f`.

Then run `print(os.getpwd())` to check that the current directory matches at both places.

If the current directory doesn't match, then call `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` inthe beginning. This will change the current directory to the scripg directory. You'll need `import os` and `import os.path`.